# Как добавить текст в поле формы при нажатии кнопки на yii?

Tags: php, yii, form

Есть таблица с кнопкой "запрос",

[image]

По нажатию которой должна открыться страница

[image]

Только в "номер зачетки" должно быть 1234. Как реализовать добавление текста в поле? Через собственный `getId` я получаю номер зачетки, но вот как подставить его в поле - проблема.

**Обновление**

Стандартная модель с представлением сгенерированная в gii. Кнопка с потугами выглядит так -

```
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'buttons'=>array(
        'preview'=>array(
            'label'=>'запрос',
            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("students/getrec", array("record_book_number"=>$data->record_book_number))',
            'click'=>$js_alert_show, 
        ),
    ),
    'template'=>'{preview}',
),
```

Comment: Решению проблемы способствует добавление в вопрос кода, который приводит к вашей проблеме. Например, как вы передаёте модель в форму?

Answer (score 1):

В экшене необходимо принять идентификатор и получить данные.

```
public function actionAnyaction( $record_book_number ){
  $model = new FormModel();
  if ( isset( $_POST['FormModel'] ) ) {
     // тут логика сохранения формы
  } else {
    $rbn = RecordBookNumber::model()->findByAttribute(array('record_book_number'=>$record_book_number));
    if ( $rbn !== null ) {
       $model->nubmer = $rbn->nubmer;
    }
  }

  // тут вывод представления и остальная логика
}
```